# Firebase Cloud Messaging - Target to single device not visible in Firebase console

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send notification to a single device in android , but when i am doing it from Firebase console , it's not visible in Firebase new view .

Could anyone help me from where do i need to send notification to a single device ?

[image]

Comment: does this answer solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53142021/7360848
if so, please accept it as answer

Comment: ya , it solves the problem . Thanks :)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Try These Steps Carefully:

1. Tap **New Notification**
2. Fill up **Notification title(Optional), Notification Text, Notification label(Optional)** and etc
3. Tap **Send Test Message** under **1. Notification**[image: test]
4. Add *Firebase Instance ID* of Your Device. To get Instance Token, check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message#access_the_registration_token) doc
5. Tap **Test** and Voila! [[image: result]]
6. You should receive your test message within a couple of seconds

Comment: I tried your solution, however, instead of single device it sends to users which are defined in Target below. -- Update: sorry it seems that it does send the message right after clicking Test. the Next button is somewhat misleading

Comment: yes, i reported them about this, the UX here is really bad

Comment: Test on device is not there

Comment: the "send test message" feature now doesn't work, it sounds a bug in their console